# Bootstrap navbar not goin right and not open collapse

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying out Bootstrap for the first time, and it dose not seems like it is working as it should. I am trying out an a example. I will make the navbar links go to the right, and when the screen gose smaller it will be an hamburger menu (also on the right side). When i am trying this, the links gose not to the right (i tryd mr-auto and ml-auto for the ul), but when the screen go smaller, it dose form as a hamburger, but it dos not go to the right and it dose not open when i click it. So that is a big issue. Nothinh happens when i click the hamburger menu.

Am i doing something wrong with my links or code? I did download the bootstrap map's js and css and added to the project and linkin to it.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<!--  bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

  <section class="containerOne">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is the solution to your problem.

See the output here - https://demo.thelovekesh.repl.co/navba.html

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="https://www.pngjoy.com/tpl/img/logo.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                            </li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

On a large screen, it looks like this.

[image]

You can also change the `container` and `expand` classes according to your needs.

Comment: Tnx, this works a lot better! Any idee why my code did not work as expexted?

Comment: You changed the container class not defined in bootstrap... and there are some errors in spacing.